# Accessing a Custom Query in Symfony2 Repository

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, dql

This is my query for getting a random product:

```
 public function getRelatedProducts()
  {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $max = $em->createQuery('SELECT MAX(p.id) FROM GlassShopBundle:Product p')->getSingleScalarResult();
        return $em->createQuery('SELECT q FROM GreenMonkeyDevGlassShopBundle:Product p WHERE p.id >= :rand ORDER BY p.id ASC')
            ->setParameter('rand',rand(0,$max))
            ->setMaxResults(1)
            ->getSingleResult()
            ->getResults(); 
    }
```

I get a `Undefined method 'getRelatedByCategory'. The method name must start with either findBy or findOneBy!` Error, which to me is strange since other queries hav worked for me and I have not really deviated. Any thoughts?

Comment: method named `getRelatedProducts`, you call `getRelatedByCategory` so whats the problem?

Comment: Just a related thing: It moans at you about "findBy" and "findOneBy" because of what's called "magic finders" in Doctrine. The "magic finders" are handled in a PHP __call function, where you end up when you call inaccessible or nonexistent methods. That message could use a change to be less misleading...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible that is a typo in called function name. Method named `getRelatedProducts`, you call `getRelatedByCategory`.